# Postgres Connection Pool Getting Exhausted after a while

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js, amazon-rds, pg

My Application is working fine like It is connecting to AWS RDS Postgres DB(There is No Connection Problem).

After some hours like in between 25-30 hours from the time we deploy, **The Connection Pool is getting exhausted and it is throwing an error**

```
TimeoutError: ResourceRequest timed out
     at ResourceRequest._fireTimeout (/yarn/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/ResourceRequest.js:62:17)
     at Timeout.bound (/yarn/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/ResourceRequest.js:8:15)
     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

I understood that I am not handling transactions well.

Here is my Code Where it is causing the Issue.

```
sequelize.transaction(async t => {
      const model = await new AssetModel({}).save({ transaction: t, returning: true })
      const createdAsset = await new Asset().loadFromModel(model)
      const tempStream = temp.createWriteStream({ dir: tmpdir() })
      try {
        await pipePromise(contentStream, tempStream)
        const stats = fs.statSync(tempStream.path)
        contentHighWaterMark = stats.size
        await promiseTimeout(
          Promise.all([
            processMetaData(tempStream.path, model, t).then(resultModel => {
              modelData = resultModel.get({ plain: true })
              return resultModel
            }),
            createUpload(tempStream.path, createdAsset)
          ]),
          UPLOAD_TIMEOUT
        )
      } finally {
        fs.unlink(tempStream.path, () => {})
      }
      return createdAsset
    })
    .then()
```

Am I doing any Wrong here?

Comment: A bug in your application: you forgot to close transactions or to return the connection to the pool. Use standard debugging techniques to find and fix the bug.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have edited the question. Please let me know where I am doing wrong.